# Is it common to use the plural when the subject is an organization?

Tags: subjects

I have seen several occurrences of the plural for the name of an organization of company, but also occurrences of the singular. For example, "Mango Ltd. have just put their new 'mPhone 8' on the market, go buy it now!" (imagine "Mango Ltd." is a famous company that manufactures mobiles phones).

> Mango Ltd. **have** just put their new 'mPhone 8' on the market

Is this sentence correct? or should it be

> Mango Ltd. **has** just put their new 'mPhone 8' on the market

or maybe both are correct?