# Is the phrase 'one pair of' considered a singular noun or a plural noun?

Tags: nouns

Which is correct, "One pair of eagles build a nest." or, "One pair of eagles builds a nest."?

Comment: Duplicate with good discussion of “Pair was or pair were

Answer (score 1):

A pair of eagles are two eagles.  --> they build a nest
A pair of scissors is one tool.  -->  it cuts paper

Comment: A pair of eagles is two eagles, but 'The bald eagle has been recently downlisted to threatened status. ...... In fact only one pair was recorded observed all summer and fall.' was the choice in the [Arrowwood ...  Wildlife ...  Report of 1994](https://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1ASRM_enGB617GB618&ei=x92yWrGCJYG0gQa01pLYBQ&q=%22only+one+pair+was+recorded%22+eagle&oq=%22only+one+pair+was+recorded%22+eagle&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i160k1.47730.49951.0.50772.6.6.0.0.0.0.100.449.5j1.6.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.5.347...33i21k1.0.gFVhe6WO3AI).

Comment: Perhaps this differs between US and UK?  See https://english.stackexchange.com/q/391871/9368

Answer (score -1):

- “A pair of eagles build a nest.”
- “A pair of eagles builds a nest.” — Present tense
- “A pair of eagles is building a nest”

The 2nd and 3rd form have similar meanings, but the 2nd one is not quite right.

An example of builds, used properly.
“Eagle pairs normally build their nest on a Tuesday, but this pair builds on a Wednesday”

Comment: **“A pair of eagles build a nest.” — Past tense** ... ??? I think Mr ctl-alt-delor's answer should be control-alt-deleted.